# Windows shell script convert all files in directory

Tags: string, windows, loops, batch-file

I'm new to this forum and never work with windows batch files but for my study thesis I need to convert meteo files (.rad) into .asc files with the following command:

```
.\gridasci.exe ver_500-2012071712.rad meteo-2012071712.asc
```

where 2012071712 is the date including time. Now I have plenty of .rad files which all have the same structure but a different date and would like to convert them into .asc files, for which a windows batch file would be great which iterates through all the files. So a sketch of the code could look like this:

```
for (all files with right format) in (this directory) do (
    date = extract date from (ver_500-date.rad)
    .\gridasci.exe ver_500-date.rad meteo-date.asc
)
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thank you very much and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%A IN (ver_500-*.rad) DO (SET "_=%%~nA"
    ECHO=.\gridasci.exe %%A meteo-!_:*-=!.asc)
ENDLOCAL
TIMEOUT -1 >NUL
EXIT/B
```

To run gridasci against the files **remove `ECHO=` from line 4** if happy with the results returned.

Comment: It helps if you mark the answer as answered if it is, or at least upvote it if you're happy with it's content.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use Windows NT command processor (cmd.exe)...

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (ver_500-*.rad) do (
    set "date=%%f"
    set "date=!date:ver_500-=!"
    set "date=!date:.rad=!"
    .\gridasci.exe ver_500-!date!.rad meteo-!date!.asc
)
```

You should probably learn about [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and how [string replace in variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) works.